# Fetch data from Google FIT API to crossplattform-App (using Xamarin,VisualStudios, C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, google-fit-api

I hope there is someone here who could help me:
Due to a project for the university I'm trying to implement a cross-platform app (using Xammarin&Visualstudios&C#). We want to send vitaldata (like steps, pulse, ecg, etc.) from our Smartwatches to the Google Fit App and then integrate the data from the Google Fit API into our own App. It's the first time I'm working with an API and I don't really understand how I can implement it. There are several examples on the internet and also instructions directly from Google (https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started), but they are not designed for Visual Studios and Xamarin. Furthermore the packages used there are not available for Xamarin.
What I have found out and implemented so far:

1. OAuth at the Google Console
2. the NuGet package is apparently called Google.Apis.Fitness.v1 (https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Fitness.v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.Fitness.v1.html)

What would be the appropriate steps to take? Do I first have to create a client and how do I do that? For example, how do I access the "steps" counter?

It would be very nice if someone could help me with the implementation.
Thanks a lot